# Intent extra is always returning null - xamarin forms - ScheduledAlarmHandler - local notifications

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a repeating reminder system in my xamarin forms application.
I have taken the code from this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-local-notification-with-repeat-interval-in-xamarin-forms/ and removed the deprecated code, modified it with the new code (notif channel, etc..)

I am able to create an intent and putextra the serialized notification string into it and start the alarm activity to fire after 15 secs. The breakpoint is firing perfectly after 15 secs, but since the received intent has a null value in the extra field, I am unable to deserialize the string and hence the application quits in debugging mode and in non-debugging mode, there is no notification received.

Here is my code:

This is a static class I use to refer to the keys...

```
public static class NotificationEssentials
{
    public static string channelId = "default";
    public static string channelName = "Default";
    public static string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";
    public static int alarmRequestCode = 8748423;
}
```

This is the NotificationService class in Android proj

```
public class LocalNotificationService : ILocalNotificationService
{
    int _notificationIconId { get; set; }
    readonly DateTime _jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    NotificationManager manager;

    public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
    {
        long repeateForMinute = 60000;
        long totalMilliSeconds = (long)(notifyTime.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;
        if (totalMilliSeconds < JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
            totalMilliSeconds = totalMilliSeconds + repeateForMinute;

        Intent intent = CreateIntent(id);
        LocalNotification localNotification = new LocalNotification
        {
            Title = title,
            Body = body,
            Id = id,
            NotifyTime = notifyTime
        };
        if (_notificationIconId != 0)
            localNotification.IconId = _notificationIconId;
        else
            localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.book;

        var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
        intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, NotificationEssentials.alarmRequestCode, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
        var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
        alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliSeconds, repeateForMinute, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void Cancel(int id)
    {
        var intent = CreateIntent(id);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, NotificationEssentials.alarmRequestCode, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
        var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
        alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
        notificationManager.CancelAll();
        notificationManager.Cancel(id);
    }

    public static Intent GetLauncherActivity()
    {
        return Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(Application.Context.PackageName);
    }

    private Intent CreateIntent(int id)
    {
        return new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(ScheduledAlarmHandler));//.SetAction("LocalNotifierIntent" + id);
    }

    private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
    {
        return Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
    }

    private string SerializeNotification(LocalNotification notification)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(notification.GetType());
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, notification);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        manager = (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(NotificationEssentials.channelName);
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(NotificationEssentials.channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = NotificationEssentials.channelDescription
            };
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        //channelInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the Broadcast receiver class

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Local Notifications Broadcast Receiver")]
public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public const string LocalNotificationKey = "LocalNotification";
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
        var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);

        //Generating notification    

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, NotificationEssentials.channelId)
            .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
            .SetContentText(notification.Body)
            .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

        var resultIntent = LocalNotificationService.GetLauncherActivity();
        resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
        var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        //Random random = new Random();
        //int randomNumber = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

        var resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(NotificationEssentials.alarmRequestCode, (int)PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
        builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Sending notification    
        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
        notificationManager.Notify(-1, builder.Build());

    }

    private LocalNotification DeserializeNotification(string notificationString)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocalNotification));
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(notificationString))
        {
            var notification = (LocalNotification)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            return notification;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the class LocalNotification?

Comment: In my PCL proj. public class LocalNotification
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int IconId { get; set; }

        public DateTime NotifyTime { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I have solved the bug. I got a new bug now. The bug is the alarm is contiually firing for every 15 secs. but i want the alarm to fire daily at the given time.

Comment: Shall i post the updated code as answer, so that you can see whats the problem..

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. I got that too. Actually i have been using 60000 ms in alarm.SetRepeating. i have changed the repeat interval to 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

Comment: Is everything working?

Comment: Yes. Working as expected

Comment: Posting the working code. may be useful for someone..

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the working code for repeating local notifications using the alarm service in respected client proj (android & ios)

This is the interface for the PCL proj

```
public interface ILocalNotificationService
{
    void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime);
    void Cancel(int id);
}
```

This is the Local Notification model class

```
public class LocalNotification
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IconId { get; set; }

    public DateTime NotifyTime { get; set; }
}
```

This is the service class used in android proj

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using YOURAPPLICATION.AppServices;
using YOURAPPLICATION.Droid;
using YOURAPPLICATION.Interfaces;
using Java.Lang;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(LocalNotificationService))]
namespace YOURAPPLICATION.Droid
{

    public static class NotificationEssentials
    {
        public static string channelId = "default";
        public static string channelName = "Default";
        public static string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";
        public static int alarmRequestCode = 8748423;
    }

    public class LocalNotificationService : ILocalNotificationService
    {
        int _notificationIconId { get; set; }
        readonly DateTime _jan1st1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
        {
            long repeatEachDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            //long repeateEachMinute = 60000;
            long totalMilliSeconds = (long)(notifyTime.ToUniversalTime() - _jan1st1970).TotalMilliseconds;
            if (totalMilliSeconds < JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
                totalMilliSeconds = totalMilliSeconds + repeatEachDay;

            Intent intent = CreateIntent(id);
            LocalNotification localNotification = new LocalNotification
            {
                Title = title,
                Body = body,
                Id = id,
                NotifyTime = notifyTime
            };
            if (_notificationIconId != 0)
                localNotification.IconId = _notificationIconId;
            else
                localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.book;

            var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
            intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

            Random generator = new Random();
            string randomNumber = generator.Next(100000, 999999).ToString("D6");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 
                Convert.ToInt32(randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliSeconds, repeatEachDay, pendingIntent);
        }

        public void Cancel(int id)
        {
            var intent = CreateIntent(id);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, NotificationEssentials.alarmRequestCode, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
            alarmManager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
            notificationManager.CancelAll();
            notificationManager.Cancel(id);
        }

        public static Intent GetLauncherActivity()
        {
            return Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(Application.Context.PackageName);
        }

        private Intent CreateIntent(int id)
        {
            return new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(ScheduledAlarmHandler)).SetAction("LocalNotifierIntent" + id);
        }

        private AlarmManager GetAlarmManager()
        {
            return Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
        }

        private string SerializeNotification(LocalNotification notification)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(notification.GetType());
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, notification);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "Local Notifications Broadcast Receiver")]
    public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public const string LocalNotificationKey = "LocalNotification";
        bool channelInitialized = false;
        NotificationManager manager;

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var extra = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKey);
            var notification = DeserializeNotification(extra);

            if (!channelInitialized)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, NotificationEssentials.channelId)
                .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
                .SetContentText(notification.Body)
                .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .BigText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."))
                .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

            var resultIntent = LocalNotificationService.GetLauncherActivity();
            resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
            stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

            var resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(randomNumber, (int)PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
            builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            // Sending notification    
            //var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);

            manager.Notify(randomNumber, builder.Build());

        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            manager = (NotificationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(NotificationEssentials.channelName);
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(NotificationEssentials.channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Default)
                {
                    Description = NotificationEssentials.channelDescription
                };
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            //channelInitialized = true;
        }

        private LocalNotification DeserializeNotification(string notificationString)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocalNotification));
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(notificationString))
            {
                var notification = (LocalNotification)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                return notification;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the IOS Service class

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using IslamicApp.iOS;
using IslamicApp.Interfaces;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LocalNotificationService))]
namespace IslamicApp.iOS
{
    public class LocalNotificationService : ILocalNotificationService
    {

        const string NotificationKey = "LocalNotificationKey";

        public void LocalNotification(string title, string body, int id, DateTime notifyTime)
        {
            var notification = new UILocalNotification
            {
                AlertTitle = title,
                AlertBody = body,
                SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName,
                FireDate = notifyTime.ToNSDate(),
                RepeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute,
                UserInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(NSObject.FromObject(id), NSObject.FromObject(NotificationKey))
            };
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
        }

        public void Cancel(int id)
        {
            var notifications = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduledLocalNotifications;
            var notification = notifications.Where(n => n.UserInfo.ContainsKey(NSObject.FromObject(NotificationKey)))
                .FirstOrDefault(n => n.UserInfo[NotificationKey].Equals(NSObject.FromObject(id)));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            if (notification != null)
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelLocalNotification(notification);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        static DateTime nsUtcRef = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        // last zero is milliseconds    

        public static double SecondsSinceNSRefenceDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return (dt.ToUniversalTime() - nsUtcRef).TotalSeconds;
        }

        public static NSDate ToNSDate(this DateTime dt)
        {
            return NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate(dt.SecondsSinceNSRefenceDate());
        }
    }
}
```

*Thats it*

> NOTE: I havent checked if this code is working as expected in IOS.

UPDATE: Here is the usage from PCL

```
var SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
var SelectedTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
var date = (SelectedDate.Date.Month.ToString("00") + "-" + SelectedDate.Date.Day.ToString("00") + "-" + SelectedDate.Date.Year.ToString());
var time = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedTime.ToString()).ToString("HH:mm");
var dateTime = date + " " + time;
var selectedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().Cancel(0);
DependencyService.Get<ILocalNotificationService>().LocalNotification("Sample Notification",
                    "Hi, This is a sample notification from Xamarin forms", 0, selectedDateTime);
```